# Allow all users to run script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have created a Google Sheet so a team can share a file in real time.  One of the sheets, I have created the following script to sort a range at a click of a button.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Sortit() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7:M107').activate()
  .sort({column: 13, ascending: false});
};
```

I can run the script on my own account but other users get a message that the script is running and then "Script [script name] experienced error" with the same details when I press details

Super new to writing script for Google Docs, so probably just permission I have not allowed

Comment: If you didn't yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Also please add more details like the execution transcript and the error details on Failed Executions from https://script.google.com

Answer (score 0):

if the sheet is shared with all the team you can try to public the script as web app. From your Script go to "Publish > Deploy as web app" this will allow your team to execute the script as you meaning every time they execute the script if there is a limit it will count on your quota, after you click on publish you will see this

[image]

Where says "who has access to this app" select what you need, everyone within the domain or anyone. This helps also when you are the admin and wants to delegate some work to a user but dont want to give admin rights to use APIs. I hope this helps, greetings

Answer (score -1):

same as you installed this script the others need to do the same otherwise it won't run for them - that's Google policy on scripts due to "safety" standards. if this is just a simple sort script then you should consider using Filtered view instead:

[image: 0]

also, there is an option to use an installable trigger (if you want to go that extra mile), meaning that it will prompt users to install the script(s) attached to the sheet